# Background image stretching

Tags: android, background

I have a background image on my layout's outer-most LinearLayout.  I simply do the following:

```
android:background="@drawable/home_background"
```

This stretches the image to the dimensions of my phone's screen (or more accurately, the dimensions of the LinearLayout).

Unfortunately, when a user clicks an EditText and the virtual keyboard shows, the image squishes because the height of the LinearLayout has shrunken.  How can I get this to not happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in Androidmanifest in activity tag use:

```
<activity
...
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

</activity>
```

for more info you may check Android Developer reference at

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

good luck,